# Searching for keys in dictionary that have a value between two numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, search

I need to analyze a dictionary for values that include a number between two given numbers (as parameters) and return those values preceded by their key

Dictionary:

```
{'P':[("Eight",1460, 225.0, 200.0, "fresco","Netherlands"),("Six",1465,81.0, 127.1, "tempera", "Netherlands")],
        'V':[("Four",1661, 148.0, 257.0,"oil paint", "Austria"),("Two",1630, 91.0, 77.0, "oil paint","USA")],
        'K':[("Five",1922,63.8,48.1,"watercolor","USA"),("Seven",1950,61.0,61.0,"acrylic paint","USA"),("Two",1965,81.3,100.3,"oil paint","United Kingdom")],
        'C':[("Ten",1496,365.0,389.0,"tempera","Italy")],
        'U':[("Nine",1203,182.0, 957.0,"egg tempera","Italy"), ("Twelve",1200,76.2,101.6,"egg tempera","France")]
        }
```

The function should only return the values where a number between the two numbers is present. So if the function was called between_two_values it should return this if searching for values between 1464 and 1496:

```
between_two_values(dictionary1(), 1464, 1496)

{'P': [('Six', 1465, 81.0, 127.1, 'tempera',    
'Netherlands')], 'C': [('Ten', 1496, 365.0, 
389.0, 'tempera', 'Italy')]}
```

If one of the values of the key doesn't have a number between 1464-1496 it shouldnt return that value and only the ones that have a number in that range preceded by its key. This is why in the above example for 'P' the first value which has 1460 wasnt returned since it is not between the 2 numbers. The first number in the function should always be smaller then the second if the first number is larger then it should just return an empty dictionary.

This is the code I have come up with I don't think it's correct but it kind of shows the logic that could solve this function. I appreciate any help I receive

```
def between_two_values(dictionary,start,end):
    for x in dictionary:
        if end < x < start in dictionary:
            return dictionary(x)
```

Comment: have you run this code of yours against the dictionary? any error messages to show?

Comment: @melgart right now it is saying TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Comment: cool, that's useful. it's saying that you're trying to compare apples and oranges. seems like you're not sure what you're comparing against in your between_two_values() function. why don't you consider putting in some print() statements in there after the for loop so you can see the data you're iterating over. remember that python dictionaries have keys that map to values and you access the dictionary like: dictionary[x]

Comment: I think the issue may be that "end" and "start" are int values and x is a str value or the other way around. I suppose maybe I could set x equal to something first and then use that in the comparison I will play around with it

Comment: Read the error message. Make changes based on it. Observe new behaviour. Repeat until no error messages appear. Welcome to writing software. Note that none of those steps actually include asking a question, but if you really must learn [ask] and include a [mcve].

Comment: So I tried changing x to int(x) and now I'm getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'P'"

Comment: ...well what integer did you expect `'P"'` to evaluate to? SO is not a tutorial service, it simply does not scale to walk you by the hand through what are pretty unambiguous error messages.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is in my original question that 'P' is one of the keys and at least in the example it should return 'P' along with its values that include a number between the two parameter numbers. I realized I forgot to ask a specific question but is there anyway my code could be revised to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Here's one solution to the problem posed.

I've formatted the data better for clarity.  When it was condensed down I didn't immediately see that each dictionary value was wrapped in a list.  Of course this is a style-oriented change, but style helps with readability.

Note that I have made a few assumptions, such as that each dictionary value will be a list.  For example, that your edge case of a key with no values will be represented as `[]` rather than `None`.  I have also sort of extrapolated what I think the desired output is from the example you gave.  Finally, you may consider using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify where matches are stored.

Besides that, this code is nothing fancy.  You certainly could condense it down more, or use classes for semantics.  Speaking of semantics, I recommend that you use better variable names than I did: "data", "record", and "value" are pretty generic, but I feel they helped explain the solution without me having insight as to what this data represents.

If you're using Python 2, consider using `dictionary.iteritems()` instead of `dictionary.items()`.

Data

```
data = {
    'P': [
        ('Eight', 1460, 225.0, 200.0, 'fresco', 'Netherlands'), 
        ('Six', 1465, 81.0, 127.1, 'tempera', 'Netherlands'), 
    ], 
    'V': [
        ('Four', 1661, 148.0, 257.0, 'oil paint', 'Austria'), 
        ('Two', 1630, 91.0, 77.0, 'oil paint', 'USA'), 
    ], 
    'K': [
        ('Five', 1922, 63.8, 48.1, 'watercolor', 'USA'), 
        ('Seven', 1950, 61.0, 61.0, 'acrylic paint', 'USA'), 
        ('Two', 1965, 81.3, 100.3, 'oil paint', 'United Kingdom'), 
    ], 
    'C': [
        ('Ten', 1496, 365.0, 389.0, 'tempera', 'Italy'), 
    ], 
    'U': [
        ('Nine', 1203, 182.0, 957.0, 'egg tempera', 'Italy'), 
        ('Twelve', 1200, 76.2, 101.6, 'egg tempera', 'France'), 
    ], 
}
```

Code

```
def between_two_values(dictionary, start, end):
    matches = {}
    for key, record_list in dictionary.items():
        for record in record_list:
            value = record[1]
            if start < value < end:
                if key in matches:
                    matches[key].append(record)
                else:
                    matches[key] = [record]
    return matches

result = between_two_values(data, 1464, 1496)
print(result)
```

Output

```
{'P': [('Six', 1465, 81.0, 127.1, 'tempera', 'Netherlands')]}
```

Comment: You know you can write: `if start < value < end:`

Comment: @AChampion Updated to reflect that.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you is there a way to return result instead of printing it? It works when printing but when I change it to return it says return outside function

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22 What is it you're trying to achieve?  It's not possible to return outside of a function because, well... where would the value be returned to?  Since it is already stored in the `result` variable, you can pass it around or do further work on it there.

Comment: That makes sense and I need to return the output inside the function instead of calling it outside the function. For example if I change return matches to print matches I don't believe it gives the output

Comment: I may have figured it out by just moving the last two lines on the same indent as return matches and changing print(result) to return result

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22 Sure, you could add a print of the matches object right before it returns from that function if desired.  In terms of designing your program, it's generally preferable to separate input and output from processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` comprehension to construct a result, e.g.:

```
>>> {k: [e for e in v if 1464 < e[1] < 1496] for k, v in dictionary.items()}
{'C': [],
 'K': [],
 'P': [('Six', 1465, 81.0, 127.1, 'tempera', 'Netherlands')],
 'U': [],
 'V': []}
```

Then just eliminate the empty results:

```
def between_two_values(dictionary, start, end):
    result = {k: [e for e in v if start < e[1] < end] for k, v in dictionary.items()}
    return {k: v for k, v in result.items() if v}
```

Comment: Nice and concise.

Comment: You can combine those using this trick: `{k: f for k, v in dictionary.items() for f in ([e for e in v if start < e[1] < end],) if f}` This adds an inner loop that only loops once. It is used to give the list a name so that it can be used in a `if` clause.

Comment: Yes, understand that you can do this but there is a balance between brevity, comprehensibility, and performance. Given the OPs handle @n00bprogrammer22, I erred on the side of more verbosity in the hope to make it more accessible :). I could have used a tuple generator for `result` to avoid the dict construction but I'm not one for being premature (in optimisation).